# Leetcode Question - First Missing Positive

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of integers, find the first missing positive integer in linear time and constant space. In other words, find the lowest positive integer that does not exist in the array. The array can contain duplicates and negative numbers as well.

For example, the input `[3, 4, -1, 1]` should give `2`. The input `[1, 2, 0]` should give `3`.

I did this but not able to find what is the error in my logic when taking input as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3BB.png). it is giving output as `undefined` instead of `2`.

```js
var firstMissingPositive = function(nums) {

  nums.sort(compare);
  var arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] > 0)
      arr.push(nums[i]);
  }

  if (arr.length == 0)
    return 1;
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (!(arr[0] == 1))
        return 1;
      else if (i > 0)
        if (!(arr[i - 1] + 1 == arr[i]))
          return i + 1;
        else if ((i + 1) == arr.length)
        return arr[i] + 1;
      else if ((arr[i] == i + 1)) // && (arr[i+1] == arr[i]+1 ))
        continue;
      else
        return i + 1;
    }
  }
};

function compare(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Output:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3BB.png]

Comment: I see your code and it seems to be too complicated (I am sure you could do this in an easier way). If you get `undefined` as output, maybe it means that you got out of the loop and ended at the end of the function where no `return` keyword is. Are you looking for the solution or help to understand the issue in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Since O(n) is a requirement, we'll have to prepare some hash table of possible numbers. It will just be the length of the input array (+2 why not), containing possible number 1..n. We iterate the input array and for each number we match (if applicable) it's position = value in the array of possible numbers. We set it to -1 so we won't choose it. Finally, we iterate the possible numbers that are left and pick the first one.

```js
var firstMissingPositive = function(nums) {

  var possible = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length + 2; i++) {
    possible.push(i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var number = nums[i];
    if (number <= nums.length && number > 0) {
      possible[number] = -1;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < possible.length; i++) {
    if (possible[i] > 0) {
      return possible[i]
    }
  }

};

console.log(firstMissingPositive([3, 4, -1, 1]))
console.log(firstMissingPositive([0, 1, 2]))
console.log(firstMissingPositive([1]))
```